# Efficient Numpy computation of pairwise squared differences

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

The following code does exactly what I want, which is to compute the pairwise sum of squares of differences between elements of a vector (length three in the example), of which I have a long series (limited to five here).  The desired result is shown at the bottom.
But the implementation feels kludgy for two reasons:

1) the need to add a phantom dimension, changing the shape from (5, 3) to (5,1,3) to avoid broadcast problems, and

2) the apparent necessity of an explicit 'for' loop, which I'm sure is why it's taking hours to execute on my much larger data set (a million vectors of length 2904).

Is there a more efficient and/or pythonic way to achieve the same result?

```
a = np.array([[ 4,  2,  3], [-1, -5,  4], [ 2,  1,  4], [-5, -1,  4], [6, -3,  3]])
a = a.reshape((5,1,3))

m = a.shape[0]
n = a.shape[2]
d = np.zeros((n,n))
for i in range(m):
    c = a[i,:] - np.transpose(a[i,:])
    c = c**2
    d += c

print d

[[   0.  118.  120.]
 [ 118.    0.  152.]
 [ 120.  152.    0.]]
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could eliminate the for-loop by using:

```
In [48]: ((a - a.swapaxes(1,2))**2).sum(axis=0)
Out[48]: 
array([[  0, 118, 120],
       [118,   0, 152],
       [120, 152,   0]])
```

Note that if `a` has shape `(N, 1, M)` then `(a - a.swapaxes(1,2))` has shape `(N, M, M)`. Make sure you have enough RAM to accommodate an array of this size. Page swapping can also slow the calculation to a crawl.

If you do have too little memory, you will have to break up the calculation in chunks:

```
m, _, n = a.shape
chunksize = 10**4
d = np.zeros((n,n))
for i in range(0, m, chunksize):
    b = a[i:i+chunksize]
    d += ((b - b.swapaxes(1,2))**2).sum(axis=0)
```

This is a compromise between performing the calculation on the entire array and
calculating row-by-row. If there are a million rows, and the chunksize is 10**4, then there will be only 100 iterations of the loop instead of a million.
Thus, it should be significantly faster than calculating row-by-row. Choose the largest value of chunksize you can which allows the calculation to be performed in RAM.

Comment: What I didn't mention (because I didn't think it was relevant to the specific issue I mentioned) is that the actual data array I'm working with is an np.memmap object occupying 12GB on disk.   I don't know offhand whether the fact that it's a memmap solves the RAM problem for the specific operation you describe at the top, though I suspect it should.  I guess I could just try it and see!

Comment: Now that I think about it, np.memmap probably doesn't automatically create a new memmap object to accommodate the (N,M,M) intermediate result, which is probably a problem.  And in my application, M=2904, so the size would 24 TB!

Answer (score 9):

If you don't mind the dependency on `scipy`, you can use functions from the [`scipy.spatial.distance`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/spatial.distance.html) library:

```
In [17]: from scipy.spatial.distance import pdist, squareform

In [18]: a = np.array([[ 4,  2,  3], [-1, -5,  4], [ 2,  1,  4], [-5, -1,  4], [6, -3,  3]])

In [19]: d = pdist(a.T, metric='sqeuclidean')

In [20]: d
Out[20]: array([ 118.,  120.,  152.])

In [21]: squareform(d)
Out[21]: 
array([[   0.,  118.,  120.],
       [ 118.,    0.,  152.],
       [ 120.,  152.,    0.]])
```

Comment: This looks intriguing.  But as discussed in response to the previous question, the size of the actual data set is large (1M x 2094).  I don't know how to evaluate the memory demands of pdist for that large of an array (which is implemented in my code as an np.memmap).  Any insights on that question?

Comment: Given `n` points, there are `n*(n-1)/2` pairwise distances to compute.  So, unless you can work in chunks (and can discard a chunk before computing the next chunk), your memory requirements are O(n^2).  `pdist` will create this array in memory.  For working in chunks and/or writing the results of the calculation directly to a memory-mapped array, you best bet is probably to start with @unutbu's answer.